# Merge two audio and one video when reeconding

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, merge

I know it seems this is answered, but I can't merge two audio files and one video.

My command is:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -i file.aac -i file.mp3 -itsoffset 4 -i file_1.mov -itsoffset 10 -i file_2.mov -filter_complex "[0:v][3:v] overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10:enable=between(t\,4\,7) [v]; [v][4:v] overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10:enable=between(t\,10\,13) [v1]" -map "[v1]" -map 1:a -map 2:a -c:v libx264 -c:a libfdk_acc -shortest -y test.mp4
```

Ffmpeg correctly creates a new file with overlays, but it doesn't add the two audio tracks, only one.
To clarify, I want to take the video from the first input, which has only one video track, and the audio from the aac and mp3 file.
What is my mistake?

This is my full console output:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -i file.aac -i file.mp3 -itsoffset 4 -i file_1.mov -itsoffset 10 -i file_1.mov -filter_complex "[0:v][3:v] overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10:enable=between(t\,4\,7) [v]; [v][4:v] overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10:enable=between(t\,10\,13) [v1]" -map "[v1]" -map 1:a -map 2:a -c copy -c:v libx264 -c:a libfdk_aac -shortest -y test.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.3.git Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug  7 2014 18:14:20 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/stuzzo/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/home/stuzzo/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/stuzzo/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/stuzzo/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      52. 98.100 / 52. 98.100
  libavcodec     55. 72.102 / 55. 72.102
  libavformat    55. 51.101 / 55. 51.101
  libavdevice    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
  libavfilter     4. 11.102 /  4. 11.102
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'file.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2014-08-27 12:22:03
  Duration: 00:00:43.65, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 698 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 568x320, 695 kb/s, 24.01 fps, 24 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2014-08-27 12:22:03
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'file.aac':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4A 
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: M4A mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2029-03-12 09:28:48
    iTunSMPB        :  00000000 00000840 00000052 00000000001D4B6E 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
  Duration: 00:00:43.58, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 126 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 115 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2029-03-12 09:28:48
Input #2, mp3, from 'battisti.mp3':
  Metadata:
    Software        : Logic Pro 8.0.2
  Duration: 00:00:43.62, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 209 kb/s
    Stream #2:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 209 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : LAME3.98r
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'file_1.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2014-09-02 14:35:01
  Duration: 00:00:03.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8631 kb/s
    Stream #3:0(eng): Video: qtrle (rle  / 0x20656C72), bgra, 120x120, 8614 kb/s, SAR 120:120 DAR 1:1, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-09-02 14:35:01
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Animation
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #3:1(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-09-02 14:35:06
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
Input #4, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'file_1.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2014-09-02 14:35:01
  Duration: 00:00:03.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8631 kb/s
    Stream #4:0(eng): Video: qtrle (rle  / 0x20656C72), bgra, 120x120, 8614 kb/s, SAR 120:120 DAR 1:1, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-09-02 14:35:01
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Animation
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #4:1(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-09-02 14:35:06
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
[libx264 @ 0x3d47bc0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x3d47bc0] profile High, level 2.1
[libx264 @ 0x3d47bc0] 264 - core 142 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    encoder         : Lavf55.51.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 568x320, q=-1--1, 24 fps, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc55.72.102 libx264
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (libfdk_aac) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2029-03-12 09:28:48
      encoder         : Lavc55.72.102 libfdk_aac
    Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (libfdk_aac) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc55.72.102 libfdk_aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
  Stream #3:0 (qtrle) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
  Stream #4:0 (qtrle) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
  Stream #2:0 -> #0:2 (mp3 (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1048 fps=228 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2795kB time=00:00:43.60 bitrate= 525.1kbits/s    
video:1381kB audio:1366kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.728943%
[libx264 @ 0x3d47bc0] frame I:5     Avg QP:19.68  size: 15730
[libx264 @ 0x3d47bc0] frame P:272   Avg QP:21.96  size:  3459
[libx264 @ 0x3d47bc0] frame B:771   Avg QP:24.28  size:   512
[libx264 @ 0x3d47bc0] consecutive B-frames:  0.8%  2.7%  2.3% 94.3%
[libx264 @ 0x3d47bc0] mb I  I16..4: 14.3% 60.5% 25.1%
[libx264 @ 0x3d47bc0] mb P  I16..4:  0.7%  1.1%  0.3%  P16..4: 61.0% 14.2% 10.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:12.7%
[libx264 @ 0x3d47bc0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8: 40.9%  0.5%  0.1%  direct: 0.6%  skip:57.8%  L0:39.2% L1:60.0% BI: 0.8%
[libx264 @ 0x3d47bc0] 8x8 transform intra:54.9% inter:68.7%
[libx264 @ 0x3d47bc0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 88.7% 95.8% 55.3% inter: 10.7% 22.5% 0.7%
[libx264 @ 0x3d47bc0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 12%  4% 36% 48%
[libx264 @ 0x3d47bc0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 15% 15% 24%  8%  8%  8%  7%  8%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x3d47bc0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 20% 23% 16%  7%  8%  7%  7%  6%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x3d47bc0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 57% 19% 17%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x3d47bc0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.7% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x3d47bc0] ref P L0: 64.7% 10.9% 19.3%  5.0%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x3d47bc0] ref B L0: 93.2%  6.1%  0.7%
[libx264 @ 0x3d47bc0] ref B L1: 96.5%  3.5%
[libx264 @ 0x3d47bc0] kb/s:259.03
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want the output to contain two stereo audio streams, or do you want to merge both stereo audio inputs into one stereo stream in the output?

Comment: The second one :)

Comment: I have answered here: https://superuser.com/a/1251856/74576

Comment: Have you got answer?
I just want to merge two audios into one video but I am unable to do it!!

Answer (score -1):

Example 1

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20use%20-map%20option

My intuition was your -map options and the article seems to verify that.

Comment: It's better to show in an answer what command you're recommending because external pages can disappear or change. I was unable to figure out how to use Example 1 to answer the posted question. However, this helped: https://superuser.com/a/1251856/74576

Comment: Much as Ryan has pointed out on his comment, the link has now rotted and disappeared.